# Modeling constraints in gurobi

Tags: modeling, python, gurobi

$$\max \lbrace 0, q_i \rbrace \le L^r_i \le \min \lbrace Q^r,Q^r+q_i \rbrace \quad \forall i\in N,r\in R$$

I am not sure if this type of question is allowed here but I am stuck at modeling this constraints for the pickup dropoff problem with time window in Python using Gurobi API. Can anyone point me in the right direction or show an example?

Comment: This type of question is definitely allowed. I suggest that you edit your question though and use [MathJax](https://or.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-do-i-use-mathjax-on-this-site) for your equation.
And also, can you clarify in your question that $Q^r$ is a positive constant and $q_i$ and $L^r_{i}$ are variables (integer and continuous)?

Comment: Thanks Ehsan! yes  Qr  is positive continuous, qi can be negative  parameter . Lri  is variable.

Comment: The good news is that max and min both appear convexly (i.e., all the constraints are convex), so no linearization, logic modeling, or introduction of binaries, etc should be needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is greater than or equal to the maximum of several items if and only if it is greater than or equal to each individual item.

Something is less than or equal to the minimum of several items if and only if it is less than or equal to each individual item.